# How to dial an extension through an android app

Tags: android, html, mobile, phone-call

Looked through all the answers and tried a few things none of them worked.

The phone number is programmed in and works on apple phones and dials the extension - but it does not work on Android.

We tried adding commas before the extension and also tried adding a "w" instead of "pp", none of these work. This was all we read when going through previous questions and responses.

For instance, we tried inputing these lines:

```html
<a href = "tel:1234567890pp509">Number here</a>

<a href = "tel:1234567890,,,509">Number here</a>

<a href = "tel:1234567890W509">Number here</a>

<a href = "tel:1234567890;509">Number here</a>
```

Any other suggestions to get this to work on Android phones?